# Exactly to what extent is Kernel structure and design dependent on the file system being used?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, kernel

For instance, lets say hypothetically that we have access to the Windows source code.

Now can we modify the source code to operate entirely on ext4 file system, instead of NTFS, just by changing the code modules that depend on the exact file system being used? Or will major changes in the way the kernel works be needed?

To what extent does the file system being used affect the kernel design?

(Note: You can switch the above example with the case of ReactOS, which is an open source clone of Windows 2000 and supports only FAT file system, and ext4.

Moreover, I know that Windows source code is not available to public so a definitive opinion cannot be given. I'm asking based on whatever is known about Windows internals, for my given example, and as per general principles of Kernel design.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the OS kernel is not dependent upon file systems. Most operating systems support multiple file systems.